# I want to use class into a input type=sumbit

Tags: html, css, class

I want to use this :

```
<input type="submit" class="but" name="versturen" value="Aankopen" action="versturen">
```

But it doesn't recognize the class but , The css is linked and the name is correct , because he does the rest of the css on my page , but not this one. Can somebody help me out with this?

Comment: show your but css code

Comment: put your class .but here

Comment: Works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FY6Ur/)!! Show your css Code

Answer (score 2):

It will work fine check the fiddle link...

```
<input type="submit" class="but" name="versturen" value="Aankopen" action="versturen">
```

```
.but{    

    /*........

      Apply your style on here

    ........*/

}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/5PY4C/)